# Integral of Dirac delta function evaluated at a differential function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I am having some troubles in evaluate the following:
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b} \delta \left( f \left(x \right)\right) f'\left( x\right) dx,
\end{align}
where $f: \left[a,b \right] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $f\left( a\right)\neq 0, f\left(b \right)\neq0$ and if $f\left( x\right) = 0$, then $f'\left( x\right) \neq 0$. How can I proceed? Thank you!

Comment: Physicist’s answer: If $f$ is $C^1$, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism in the neighborhood of its zeros. So split the integral around each zero of $f$ and change variables so that the integral is of $\delta(y)dy$ and you are done. It’s not a mathematician’s answer because it seems a nonobvious task to properly define $\delta \circ f$.

Comment: @Mindlack That helped a lot! I didn't know this fact about the f being a diffeomorphism inthe neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the substitution $y=f(x)$ you get:
$$I=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}\delta(y)dy$$
and this would be $I=1$ if $0\in[f(a),f(b)]$ or $I=0$ if $0\notin[f(a),f(b)]$

---

To answer your comment, remember that:
$$\int_a^b\delta(x)dx=1,\,0\in[a,b]$$
since the function $\delta$ has one peak for every zero for the function inside of it. So for a function $f(x)$ with $n$ roots $i=[1,n],\,\alpha_i\in[a,b]$ we can say that there will be $n$ delta peaks within the region $[a,b]$ and so:
$$\int_a^b\delta(f(x))dx=\int_a^b\sum_{i=1}^n\delta(x-\alpha_i)dx=n$$

As for the second part, notice that if we use the same substitution as in the original question we get:
$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}\delta(y)\frac{|f'(x)|}{f'(x)}dy=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}\delta(y)\operatorname{sgn}(y')dy$$
Now think about what this represents

Comment: Nice! That solves this problem! I have two more questions (they are small):
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b} \delta(f(x)) dx
\end{align}
is $0$ if $f(x) \neq 0$, for all $x \in [a,b]$ or $n$ if $f$ has $n$ zeros in $[a,b]$?

And
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b} \delta(f(x)) |f'(x)| dx
\end{align}
can use the same argument as yours? Thank you!

Comment: I have added to my answer to answer your comment hopefully

Comment: $I = -1$ if $f(b) < 0 < f(a)$. Also, $\int_a^b \delta(f(x)) dx \neq n$. The general formula is
$$\delta(f(x)) =
\sum_{x_k: f(x_k) = 0} \frac {\delta(x - x_k)} {|f'(x_k)|}$$
($\delta(2 x)$ is not defined to be the same as $\delta(x)$).